# Ubuntu partition won't boot after cloning using dd

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, dd

I have a Ubuntu 14.0.4 server. The goal is to have kickstart install 2 Ubuntu installations side by side dual-bootable.

Ubuntu is installed OK on `sdaX`. I have used `dd` to clone this to `sdaY`. I have changed the UUID, `fstab` and can even boot into `sdaX` and view the contents of `sdaY`. However when I attempt to boot into `sdaY` I get `/sbin/init No such file or directory` and a Kernel panic.

I have edited grub to make sure it's looking at `sdaY`.

Can anyone think of anything I have missed to make this partition bootable Failing this, any way to repair the Ubuntu install using command line.

**Note:** Both `fdisk -l sda1` and `sda5` say no partition table found.

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    13672447     6835200   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        13674494    41940991    14133249    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        13674496    27344895     6835200   83  Linux
/dev/sda6        27346944    29298687      975872   83  Linux
/dev/sda7        29300736    31252479      975872   83  Linux
/dev/sda8        31254528    33206271      975872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9        33208320    41940991     4366336   83  Linux
```

---

```
Disk /dev/sda1: 6999 MB, 6999244800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 850 cylinders, total 13670400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000 Disk /dev/sda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

---

```
Disk /dev/sda5: 6999 MB, 6999244800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 850 cylinders, total 13670400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000Disk /dev/sda5 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

---

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="xxx" UUID="ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35" TYPE="ext4"
```

---

```
/dev/sda5: LABEL="yyy" UUID="9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062" TYPE="ext4"
```

---

```
    #
    # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
    #
    # It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
    # from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
    #

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
    if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
      set have_grubenv=true
      load_env
    fi
    if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
       set default="${next_entry}"
       set next_entry=
       save_env next_entry
       set boot_once=true
    else
       set default="0"
    fi

    if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
      menuentry_id_option="--id"
    else
      menuentry_id_option=""
    fi

    export menuentry_id_option

    if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
      set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
      save_env saved_entry
      set prev_saved_entry=
      save_env prev_saved_entry
      set boot_once=true
    fi

    function savedefault {
      if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
        saved_entry="${chosen}"
        save_env saved_entry
      fi
    }
    function recordfail {
      set recordfail=1
      if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
    }
    function load_video {
      if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
        insmod all_video
      else
        insmod efi_gop
        insmod efi_uga
        insmod ieee1275_fb
        insmod vbe
        insmod vga
        insmod video_bochs
        insmod video_cirrus
      fi
    }

    if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
       font=unicode
    else
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
    fi
        font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
    fi

    if loadfont $font ; then
      set gfxmode=auto
      load_video
      insmod gfxterm
      set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
      set lang=en_IE
      insmod gettext
    fi
    terminal_output gfxterm
    if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
      set timeout=30
    else
      if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
        set timeout_style=hidden
        set timeout=0
      # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
      # unavailable.
      elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
        set timeout=0
      fi
    fi
    ### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
    set menu_color_normal=white/black
    set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
    ### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
    function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
        if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
            set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
        else
            set vt_handoff=
        fi
    }
    if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
      if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
        if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
          if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
            set linux_gfx_mode=keep
          else
            set linux_gfx_mode=text
          fi
        else
          set linux_gfx_mode=text
        fi
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
    export linux_gfx_mode
    menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
    }
    submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-27-generic-advanced-ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35' {
            recordfail
            load_video
            gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
            insmod gzio
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            set root='hd0,msdos1'
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
            fi
            echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-27-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-27-generic-recovery-ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35' {
            recordfail
            load_video
            insmod gzio
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            set root='hd0,msdos1'
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35
            fi
            echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=ed2dff21-3aa4-43a1-b0fc-6a56b4bc1c35 ro recovery nomodeset 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
        }
    }

    ### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

    ### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
    menuentry 'Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
    }
    submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (14.04) (on /dev/sda5)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu (on /dev/sda5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic--9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            set root='hd0,msdos5'
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
            fi
            linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
            initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-27-generic (on /dev/sda5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic--9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            set root='hd0,msdos5'
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
            fi
            linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
            initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-27-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda5)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic-root=UUID=9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062 ro recovery nomodeset-9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062' {
            insmod part_msdos
            insmod ext2
            set root='hd0,msdos5'
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062
            fi
            linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=9f212aba-a7da-4137-a311-e517e11fb062 ro recovery nomodeset
            initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
        }
    }

    set timeout_style=menu
    if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
      set timeout=10
    fi
    ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
    ### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
    # This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
    # menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
    # the 'exec tail' line above.
    ### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

    ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
    if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
      source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
    elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
      source $prefix/custom.cfg;
    fi
    ### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: Mots possibly a GRUB issue - post grub.cfg , $(fdisk -l /dev/sda) and $(blkid /dev/sdaY)

Comment: $(blkid /dev/sda1) and $(blkid /dev/sda5) are needed

Comment: Thanks @EugenRieck. These have changed since my previous post as i have reinstalled. i will edit the above to reflect.

Comment: What did you mean by "I have edited grub…"? `ed2dff21-3aa4…` is in your `grub.cfg` for every Linux. Was the file generated prior the change of `/dev/sda5` UUID? If so, run `update-grub` again, it should fix at least this problem.

Comment: Updated now @KamilMaciorowski  . must have pasted the file before i did an update-grub. Thanks.

Comment: Should mention, @KamilMaciorowski, if i now reboot and select the 2nd Ububtu, sda5, it drops me into the original Ubuntu, sda1.

Comment: Original? I would rather expect this with non-updated UUIDs. Is the UUID updated also in `/etc/fstab` residing in `/dev/sda5`? Also: update the question; it still mentions `/sbin/init No such file or directory` while it's not the case anymore and the file is updated. Hardly anyone will read all the comments. The question should show your problem in one coherent state in the first place. I suggest to inform about your meaningful progress in the question body like this (e.g.): "EDIT: As (who?) suggested I did (what?) and now my setup behaves (like what?)". It's easier to track progress this way.

Answer (score 0):

After your changes, you no longer have a `GRUB` problem, but a simple `/etc/fstab` problem: After cloning, your `fstab` will be the same on `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda5`, so you will need to edit the version on `/dev/sda5` and have it point at the new UUID for the root file system.

Comment: Thanks @EugenRieck , when i do that it appears to boot into sda5 without issues however i am seeing all the files i have from sda1. sda1 is mounted and i can see the same files. fdisk -l still shows * beside sda1. Strange one. Any ideas? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a community wiki on that topic: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition

Steps are too many to fit here, and probably will be subject to updates, so no point of maintaining the same steps here, hence only the link.

EDIT: I've managed to shorten this list a lot, for my case (cloning original partition `/dev/sda1` to a new/larger partition `/dev/sda4` on the same hdd), so here are the steps:

0. of course, first make a backup of everything important, that goes without saying
1. while still running the original linux, copy the original partition to a new/larger partition and [mark it as bootable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343429/set-bootable-partition-command-line):

`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sda4 bs=1M`

2. generate a new UUID for the new partition (and copy it in the clipboard, you'll need it later):

`tune2fs -U random /dev/sda4`

3. mount the new partition to be able to access files on it:

`mkdir /mnt/new && mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/new`

4. update `etc/fstab` file on new partition and change the UUID of the root partition, using the UUID from step 2):

`nano /mnt/new/etc/fstab` or `gedit /mnt/new/etc/fstab`

5. run `update-grub` to detect/configure your new partition in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (probably that new `menuitem` will be added somewhere near the end of the grub.cfg file)
6. edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file and find that new menuitem that  previous step has added to the file, and make sure you update the line which reads something like:

`linux /boot/vmlinuz-X.X.X-XX-generic root=UUID=<here we need to type the new UUID from step 2> ...`

7. copy `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from the original partition to a new partition (which you mounted in step 3), overwriting the previous file:

`cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /mnt/new/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

You should now be ready to reboot. On the GRUB screen, choose the newly added menu item for the new partition. During the boot, the /boot/grub/grub.cfg from the original partition (/dev/sda1) will be read, but it will boot you into a new partition (/dev/sda4). Once it's booted, you can run `grub-install /dev/sda` to update MBR on /dev/sda, from which point you can stop using the original partition.